# Failed to Start Mysql (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My server space was full and I removed some temp and log files including clearing the /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 and /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0. But when I try to start or restart the mysql I get this error :

```
MariaDB server PID file could not be found!                [FAILED]
Starting MariaDB.180529 21:21:49 mysqld_safe Logging to '/home/vpssim.demo/logs/mysql.log'.
180529 21:21:49 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
.                                                          [FAILED]
Failed to restart server.                                  [FAILED]
```

There is logs in /home/vpssim.demo/logs/mysql.log file :

```
2018-05-29 20:35:05 140511035451520 [Warning] InnoDB: Using innodb_file_format is deprecated and the parameter may be removed in future releases. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-file-format/
2018-05-29 20:35:05 140511035451520 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-05-29 20:35:05 140511035451520 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-05-29 20:35:05 140511035451520 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2018-05-29 20:35:05 140511035451520 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-05-29 20:35:05 140511035451520 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-05-29 20:35:05 140511035451520 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2018-05-29 20:35:05 140511035451520 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 48M, instances = 1, chunk size = 48M
2018-05-29 20:35:05 140511035451520 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-05-29 20:35:05 140510617163520 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2018-05-29 20:35:05 140511035451520 [ERROR] InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 size 1024 is too small
2018-05-29 20:35:05 140511035451520 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2018-05-29 20:35:05 140511035451520 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2018-05-29 20:35:06 140511035451520 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-05-29 20:35:06 140511035451520 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-05-29 20:35:06 140511035451520 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-05-29 20:35:06 140511035451520 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2018-05-29 20:35:06 140511035451520 [ERROR] Aborting
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you change(updated or removed) some apache server files manually ? and seem like there is also process Id conflict. Shutdown the server completely and start it again

Comment: Hello. No I didn't change server files manually. And it is not apache, it is nginx.I restarted server and it is still same.

Comment: I found solution with deleting ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files. MariaDB still doesnt work but Mysql does.